# Semantic UI dropdown lags entire ui when setting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, semantic-ui, dropdown

I have a **large select with about ~1500 items** in it. Whenever i call this code

```
$('#multi-select').dropdown('set exactly', ['my value']);
```

to set its value, **the entire UI locks up and lags**. Now I know this is due to the large dropdown (1500 items) but I'd like to know if there is a way to keep that many items without flushing the user experience down the toilet.

I've put together an example below. You can try clicking the button once, or multiple times consecutively to see the browser choke.

http://jsfiddle.net/qhy9do4w/1/

Answer (score 2):

I've looked in the code and profiled the click. Somewhere in its bowels Semantic fires a lot of events and most of the lag time is taken by module.trigger something. Inside the code looks like this:

```
trigger: {
  change: function() {
    var
      events       = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents'),
      inputElement = $input[0]
    ;
    if(inputElement) {
      module.verbose('Triggering native change event');
      events.initEvent('change', true, false);
      inputElement.dispatchEvent(events);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't see any way to disable the event handling part.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into the semantic.js code for the dropdown set exactly and it is quite something: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/74fea12e1fd548cb870872ba5ed59f5acdcc57ba/dist/components/dropdown.js#L2219:L2295

You could try figure if the code is slow somewere or wether you can do any sort of shortcut.

But, that is hard and you might want to think about an alernative like a [search](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html).

Comment: I have to be able to select multiple values. I'm not sure if you can use search with multiple values or not

Comment: Of course you can, simply use the `onSelect` callback to add values to a list, maybe as checkboxes, whatever suits you.

Comment: no i meant the semantic ui multiple values feature, like in the example. Click on the dropdown, and click on multiple values.

Comment: I do understand you and onSelect will allow you that. You type into the search field, select one, that gets added to the list, then you type the next one, select and it gets added. Really the best solution for large lists like tags.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to simply cache the contents and only put in a selected subset of options into the drop down itself.